# PHP Syntax [''xyz'']?

Tags: php, joomla, syntax

On http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component and other joomla docs there's often a syntax like:

```
function [''Componentname'']ParseRoute($segments){
  ...
}
```

I've never seen the `[''Componentname'']` syntax, and didn't find it on php.net too.

Is this even PHP (instead of being some weird placeholder convention on joomla.org), if yes, how does it work?

EDIT: it looks like some sort of Macro, but afaik PHP doesn't do any preprocessing

Comment: Most likely they put it as a placeholder you're supposed to substitute. IE: `function MyComponentParseRoute...`

Comment: Looks like an example in the documentation, nothing more. It's not actual syntax. Not well done documentation.

Comment: Joomla depends a lot on parsing the names of things.  If you follow the naming conventions many things are taken care of for you.  So for com_content you would have ContentParseRoute. Always follow the uppercase/lower case patterns since those matter to the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not real php code, just showed as an example.

The `[Componentname]` in `[Componentname]ParseRoute` is just the placeholder, means that you should have such function like below:

```
// where foo is the name for your component
function fooParseRoute($segments){

}
```